# Cómo mostrar una imagen almacenada en un directorio y una base de datos MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hice el siguiente código y me muestra todo, el título, fecha, descripción pero no la imagen, me podrían ayudar a revisar o darme una sugerencia, me muestra lo demás pero no la imagen, no presenta errores de sintaxis, me muestra un cuadro en blanco, mi tabla se llama contenido y tiene los campos, título, fecha, descripción e imagen
aquí esta mi código

```
     $miconsulta = "SELECT * FROM contenido order by Fecha DESC";

     if ($resultado=mysqli_query ($conexion, $miconsulta)){

     while ($registro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

    echo "<h3>"  .  $registro ['Titulo'] . "</h3>";

    echo "<h3>"  .  $registro ['Fecha'] . "</h3>";

   echo "<div style='width:400px'>" .$registro ['Descripcion'] . "</div><br/><br/>";

   if ($registro ['Imagen'] !=""){

   echo "<img src='imagenes/  ". $registro['Imagen'] . " ' width='400px' height='240px' />";

                           }
  echo "<hr/>";

    } 

  }
```

Comment: en tu base de datos, como guardas la imagen?, guardas solo el nombre o lo guardas como tipo blob?

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que veo tu estas poniendo una ruta concatenado con el binario de tu imagen, te daré los siguientes consejos:

1. Si vas a utilizar imágenes, mejor guardarlas en una carpeta especifica y ve a llamar solo la ruta.
2. Sino quieres hacer eso y las guardas en la base de datos como binarias, esta es la manera correcta de hacerlo:

Tienes que especificar en el src lo que contiene con **data:image/jpeg;base64** luego la imagen (binario) codificado en **base64**

```html
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($registro['Imagen']) .'" />';
```

Comment: amigo y en caso de querer insertar mas registros, por ejemplo ese codigo es para insertar varias publicaciones, como quedaria la respuesta para que me inserte las demas imagenes

Comment: De la misma manera. Supongo que quieres iterar el arreglo proveniente de la base de datos, para eso tienes que utilizar un ciclo y en cada ejecución de ese ciclo, escribo el echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($registro['Imagen']) .'" />'; donde $registro['Imagen'] es la imagen que le corresponde.